# Knockout custom binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I've written a custom binding for KnockoutJS which renders `<select>` elements with `<optgroup>` children.

When run, this binding adds `<optgroup>` and `<option>` DOM elements.

In order to make the binding two-way I obviously need to 'record' the observables for each of those newly-added DOM elements. I've done this using

```
ko.utils.domData.set(option, "data", thisOption);
```

and then in order to retrieve the observable (or plain object) I call

```
ko.utils.domData.get(node, "data");
```

This works fine. However, in Knockout's native bindings I can call `ko.dataFor(element)` and retrieve the observable, yet this doesn't work in my custom binding.

Can anyone tell me if I've gone about this the right/wrong way? And if wrong, how do I 'record' data that `ko.dataFor` can retrieve?

Furthermore, my custom binding accepts a parameter which is the property that the selected element's observable is assigned to (in exactly the same way that Knockout's [native `options` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html) uses the 'value' parameter). So in that same change-handler I retrieve this property using the same methodology as above - *i.e.* using `ko.utils.domData...`

Is this the correct approach for assigning a selected value to another observable in a change handler?

```
ko.bindingHandlers.groupedOptions = {
"init": function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
    ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "change", function () {
        var value = valueAccessor(),
            property = ko.utils.domData.get(element, "property");
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(element.getElementsByTagName("option"), function(node) {
            if (node.selected) {
                var data = ko.utils.domData.get(node, "data");
                if (typeof(property) === "function") {
                    property(data);
                } else if (typeof(property) === "string") {
                    var vm = ko.dataFor(element);
                    if (vm !== null) {
                        vm[property] = data;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });
},
"update": function(element, valueAccessor) {

    // Get the parameters

    var h = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());

    var groups = h["groups"],
        groupsCollection,
        groupsLabel = "Label",          // the convention for this property
        optionsCollProp = "Options",    // the convention for this property
        optionsTextProp = "Text",       // the convention for this property
        optionsValProp = "Value",       // the convention for this property
        optionsValue = null;

    if (typeof (groups) === "undefined" || !groups) {
        throw "The \"groupedOption\" binding requires a \"groups\" object be specified.";
    } else {
        groupsCollection = groups["coll"];
    }
    if (!groupsCollection) {
        throw "The \"groupedOption\" binding's \"groups\" object requires that a collection (array or observableArray) be specified.";
    }
    if (typeof (groups["label"]) === "string" && groups["label"].length) {
        groupsLabel = groups["label"];
    }
    if (typeof (groups["options"]) === "object") {
        var options = groups["options"];
        if (typeof (options["coll"]) === "string" && options["coll"].length) {
            optionsCollProp = options["coll"];
        }
        if (typeof (options["text"]) === "string" && options["text"].length) {
            optionsTextProp = options["text"];
        }
        if (typeof (options["value"]) === "string" && options["value"].length) {
            optionsValProp = options["value"];
        }
    }
    var selectedItem = h["value"],
        selectedValue = ko.unwrap(selectedItem);
    if (typeof(selectedItem) === "function") {
        ko.utils.domData.set(element, "property", selectedItem);    // this records the subscribing property, i.e., the property which stores the selected item
    } else if (typeof(selectedItem) === "string") {
        // this caters for the situation whereby the subscribing property is not an observable
        ko.utils.domData.set(element, "property", selectedItem);    // this records the name of the subscribing property, i.e., the property which stores the selected item
    }


    // find how many elements have already been added to 'element'
    var childCount = 0,
        children = element.childNodes,
        childMax = children.length;
    for (var c = 0; c < childMax; c++) {
        if (children[c].nodeType != 3) {
            childCount++;
        }
    }


    // Default <option> element

    // if 'element' is currently empty then add the default <option> element
    if (!childCount) {
        var defaultText = h["optionsCaption"];
        if (defaultText && typeof(defaultText) === "string" && defaultText.length) {
            var defaultOption = document.createElement("option");
            defaultOption.innerHTML = defaultText;
            element.appendChild(defaultOption);
        }
    } else {
        // if 'element' is not empty then decrement realChildren by 1, which represents the default <option> element
        childCount--;
    }


    // now it's time to loop through each <optgroup>
    // in this loop, i is set to the the index in the collection which marks the start of the newly-added items, skipping items already added (which were counted above)
    var coll = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(groupsCollection);
    childMax = coll.length;
    for (; childCount < childMax; childCount++) {

        var groupLabel = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(coll[childCount][groupsLabel]);

        // if there is no label for this <optgroup> then don't add the <optgroup>
        if (!groupLabel || !groupLabel.length) {
            continue;
        }

        var optGroup = document.createElement("optgroup");
        optGroup.setAttribute("label", groupLabel);

        // loop through each <option>
        // determine whether the <option>s collection is an array or an observableArray
        var options = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(coll[childCount][optionsCollProp]);
        for (var j = 0, jMax = options.length; j < jMax; j++) {

            var thisOption = options[j],
                optionText = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(thisOption[optionsTextProp]);

            // if there is no text for this <option> then don't add the <option>
            if (!optionText || !optionText.length) {
                continue;
            }

            var option = document.createElement("option");
            option.innerHTML = optionText;

            // add the 'value' attribute if it exists
            var val = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(thisOption[optionsValProp]);
            if (val && val.length) {
                option.setAttribute("value", val);
            }

            // if this is the same object as the 'value' parameter then indicate so             
            if (thisOption === selectedValue) {
                option.setAttribute("selected", "selected");
            }

            // add the observable to this node so that we may retrieve this data in future
            ko.utils.domData.set(option, "data", thisOption);

            // now add this <option> to the parent <optgroup>
            optGroup.appendChild(option);
        }

        element.appendChild(optGroup);
    }

    return true;
}
};
```

Comment: Furthermore, it sounds like your code is not working the way you want it to. Please only submit working code.

Comment: Ok, I've now added the JS in question. @konijn - yes it is working as expected. My question asks "if I've gone about this the right/wrong way?" and later "Is this the correct approach". What made you think it wasn't working?

Comment: @avi: *'yet this doesn't work in my custom binding.'*

Comment: @konijn - my question is clearly asking for advice, not a solution. If you have nothing to suggest or no guidance to offer then you don't need to return to this post.

Comment: Just a note cause it was bothering me a bit reading your code `typeof` isn't a function and is usually written `typeof x` instead of `typeof(x)`

Comment: Ok, I'll take that on-board. I think I probably used the function-like call because I'm primarily a C# developer, but I'm happy to change it if `typeof x` is more prevalent in JavaScript.

Answer (score 3):

From a once over:

- You use the following type of coding a ton:

  ```
  var groupsLabel = "Label";
  ...
  if (typeof (groups["label"]) === "string" && groups["label"].length) {
    groupsLabel = groups["label"];
  }
  ```

  You could consider using a helper function for that

  ```
  function getStringValue( s , defaultValue )
  {
    return (typeof s === "string" && s.length) ? s : defaultValue;
  }
  ```

  Then you can

  ```
   var groupsLabel,
       optionsCollProp,     
       optionsTextProp,     
       optionsValProp,    
       optionsValue,                                             

   groupsLabel = getStringValue( groups.label, "Label" );

   if (typeof (groups["options"]) === "object") {
     var config = groups["options"];
     optionsCollProp = getStringValue( config.coll , "Options" );
     optionsTextProp = getStringValue( config.text , "Text" );
     optionsValProp  = getStringValue( config.value, "Value" );        
   }
  ```

  Note that I also changed `options["something"]` to `options.something` which is the preferred style in JavaScript.
- You use `var options` twice, the meaning of `options` is different in the 2 usages, I would use `config` instead the first time as in my counter proposal above this point.
- You do not use `var value = valueAccessor()` as far as I can tell
- You do not use `optionsValue = null;` as far as I can tell
- Some variables are perhaps too Spartan `vm` -> `viewModel` ?
- `.nodeType != 3` <- This could use a line of comment, given the otherwise excellent level of commenting

As for your actual question, I see nothing wrong with your approach.

Comment: default is a reserved word by the way and you have some syntax errors like `getStringValue( groups["label"]), "Label" );`

Comment: Those are great comments, @konijn. I've implemented them all except for the first one, regarding the `getStringValue` function: the problem here is, if the `groups["options"] !== "object"` then the default values are never set. `groups["options"]` is an optional parameter, so it could feasably be `!== "object"` and in that case the defaults wouldn't be set.   But other than that, great suggestions - thanks.